# How to download first emails attachment using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, email, automation, outlook

I'm getting an automatic weekly email with an attachment, and with an outlook rule, it is being saved in a folder in my inbox. my goal is to create a PowerShell script that downloads the attachment from the email with the latest "ReceivedTime". I have managed to sort the Object in the folder by "ReceivedTime" and get the latest email in the list: "$emails[0]", I can see the name of the attachment but I cannot seem to find how to download the file itself.
the error I get is as follows: **"You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression."**

my code look like this:

```
$outlook = New-Object -ComObject outlook.application
$mapi = $outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI");

#Get Folder path
$filePath = "C:\Temp\test"
$inbox = $mapi.GetDefaultFolder(6) 
$inbox.Folders | Select-Object FolderPath
$olFolderPath = "\\DanielMol@sodastream.com\Inbox\compliance"

#Get Emails Items from folder
$targetFolder = $inbox.Folders | Where-Object { $_.FolderPath -eq $olFolderPath } 


#Sort Emails in folder by date
$emails = $targetFolder.Items | Sort-Object ReceivedTime -Descending

#download attachements
$emails[0].Attachments | Select-Object $_.saveasfile(($filePath))
```

I'm using this guide to download the attachment, but my use case is a bit different from what is described in the article: https://bronowski.it/blog/2020/09/saving-outlook-attachments-with-powershell/

Sorry if it is a very simple task, I'm new to PowerShell and just learning automation.
Thank you very much :)

Comment: Use format-table to help debug and see the objects.  First use : $inbox | Format-Table.  Then do same with child items like $inbox.Folders | Format-Table.  Format-Table does a great job of enumerating through object and giving the fields.  I also like using foreach loops rather using piping when debugging so I would have a foreach for folders : Foreach($folder in inbox.Folder){ $folder | Format-Table} to see what properties are in each folder.  Each folder may have different properties.  The sample code may not be using the same properties you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I've noticed the following code:

```
#Sort Emails in folder by date
$emails = $targetFolder.Items | Sort-Object ReceivedTime -Descending
```

Instead, you need to use the [Sort](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.items.sort) method of the `Items` class which sorts the collection of items by the specified property. The index for the collection is reset to 1 upon completion of this method. So, to get the first item use the 1 index instead of 0.

```
$emails[1].Attachments[1].SaveAsFile(($filePath))
```

Be aware, the [Attachments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.attachments) object contains a set of `Attachment` objects that represent the attachments in an Outlook item. Use the `Attachments` property to return the `Attachments` collection for any Outlook item (except notes).